# .zip file downloaded as f.txt file - springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, download

Below code is always downloading a `f.txt` file rather downloading without the  actual file name and extension(here .zip extension).

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/files/{fileId}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/zip")
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> downloadFile(@PathVariable("fileId") String fileName) {
        log.info("Downloading file..!!!!");
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.valueOf("application/zip"));
        log.info("Content info : "+headers.getContentType().toString());
        File file = FileUtils.getFile("backup/" + fileName + ".zip");
        log.info("File name is : "+file.getName());
        FileSystemResource fileSystemResource = new FileSystemResource(file);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(fileSystemResource, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

It would be great if someone can let me know where the mistake is/ some amendments to be done?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`f.txt` is coming from the `Content-Disposition` response header. This is a consequence of fixing [cve-2015-5211](https://pivotal.io/security/cve-2015-5211) (RFD Attack)

Comment: So use `headers.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", "my.zip");` or such.

Answer (score 4):

To fix the issue, add the `content-disposition` and `content-length` headers:

```
...
log.info("File name is : "+file.getName());

// Adding the following two lines should fix the download for you:
headers.set("content-disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"");
headers.set("content-length", String.valueOf(file.length()));

FileSystemResource fileSystemResource = new FileSystemResource(file);
...
```